# How to read & run SQL(on Snowflake) from a .txt file in a folder using SAS Studio and export the o/p to excel?

Tags: sql, sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sas-macro

I have some .txt files with SQL code in them for Snowflake database in a folder on SAS Studio. I need my logic to pick and read the .txt files from the folder and run-on snowflake using SAS Studio and need the output of the code in excel files.

Expecting help with the process and detailed steps on how to achieve this? I am new to SAS and good with SQL.

With the help of the below code I was able to read SQL from a text file, run out SAS and export the output to a .csv file. But I need to read multiple text file from a folder and create .csv output for all of them separately. Please see the code below and help me how to achieve this for multiple text files.

```
data _null_;             *reading the SQL script into a variable, hopefully under 32767?;
infile "/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/SQLs/Query.txt" recfm=f lrecl=32767 pad;
input @1 sqlcode $32767.;
call symputx('sqlcode',sqlcode);  *putting it into a macro variable;
run;

proc sql;
connect to odbc as mycon (complete="DRIVER={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};
SERVER=;
UID=&usr.;
PWD=&pwd.;
WAREHOUSE=;
DATABASE=;
SCHEMA=;
dbcommit=10000 autocommit=no
readbuff=200 insertbuff=200;");

create table final_export as
select * from connection to mycon(&sqlcode.);
disconnect from mycon;
quit;

proc export data = work.final_export
outfile = "/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/Report/final_report.csv"
DBMS = csv REPLACE;
run;
```

Comment: If you don't have any code you need help with, move this discussion to forums on http://communities.sas.com/

Comment: I have mentioned the code I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for multiple files by defining and using a SAS macro:

```
%macro file_input (INPUTXT=,OUTPUTCSV=);

data _null_;  
infile "&INPUTTXT." recfm=f lrecl=32767 pad;
input @1 sqlcode $32767.;
call symputx('sqlcode',sqlcode);  *putting it into a macro variable;
run;

proc sql;
connect to odbc as mycon (complete="DRIVER={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};
SERVER=;
UID=&usr.;
PWD=&pwd.;
WAREHOUSE=;
DATABASE=;
SCHEMA=;
dbcommit=10000 autocommit=no
readbuff=200 insertbuff=200;");

create table final_export as
select * from connection to mycon(&sqlcode.);
disconnect from mycon;
quit;

proc export data = work.final_export
outfile = "&OUTPUTCSV."
DBMS = csv REPLACE;
run;

%mend;

/* 3 Examples for macro calls */

%file_input (INPUTTXT=%str(/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/SQLs/Query.txt),
             OUTPUTCSV=%str(/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/Report/final_report.csv));
%file_input (INPUTTXT=%str(/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/SQLs/Query2.txt),
             OUTPUTCSV=%str(/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/Report/final_report2.csv));
%file_input (INPUTTXT=%str(/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/SQLs/Query3.txt),
             OUTPUTCSV=%str(/dslanalytics-shared/dgupt12/Report/final_report3.csv));
```